SAPUI5 - RichTextEditor disappears when json model is updated
I have a form which contains some Input fields, some Comboboxes and a RichTextEditor.

When I change one of the Comboboxes there is a custom function that changes some properties in a JSON Model. When that happens, RichTextEditor disappears from the page. Looking at the DOM I noticed that DIV element is there, TextArea element is also there but the iframe is gone.


I tried to comment the function that changes model properties and it works, but I really need to change those properties when changing the Combobox.
The Rich Text Editor is defined in the view as follow:
<rte:RichTextEditor id="rteDesc" value="{/value}" ready="onEditorReady" showGroupClipboard="false" change="onUpdateDescription" width="100%"/>

I tried to remove the Rich Text Editor and create a new one but the one created only displays a text area without the toolbar.

Guess we need more information. I modified the sample from the UI5 docs and it worked flawlessly. RTE is bound to JSONModel, model changes on button press, RTE is auto refreshed with new model value. Pls show more of your JS code. Are there any console errors?
